# chef. how to set/use local_settings in application_python 4.0 cookbook?

Tags: django, chef-infra

I am using [application_python v4.0](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/application_python/versions/4.0.0) cookbook, mostly successfully,
but running into a bit of a snag on the local_settings generation.

Basically, I would like change the contents of the settings.py.erb
that is being used.

This is the cookbook's berkshelf source location:

**.berkshelf/cookbooks/application_python-4.0.0/templates/settings.py.erb**

I've added a modified settings.py.erb on my own cookbook, but it is
not getting picked up and the default .berkshelf file is always being
used.

**myrepo/cookbooks/basedjango/templates/settings.py.erb**

Then I read up on the local_settings attribute and thought I would
modify it to point to a renamed file, settings2.py.erb instead.  Initially, my idea was just to track which template directories it would be searching in.  But never managed to modify local_settings.

These are various adjustments I tried, with the resulting error in
most cases.

```
# local_settings 'foo' do
#   source 'settings2.py.erb'
# end
#   resulting error => undefined method `local_settings' for PoiseApplicationPython::Resources::Django::Resource

# local_settings do
#   source 'settings2.py.erb'
# end
#   resulting error => undefined method `local_settings' for PoiseApplicationPython::Resources::Django::Resource

# local_settings 'settings2.py.erb'
#                     undefined method `local_settings' for PoiseApplicationPython::Resources::Django::Resource

# file 'local_settings' do
#   source 'settings2.py.erb'
# end
```

Question:  Why is my own cookbook's template not being picked up and used, instead of the berkshelf version?  Works on other cookbooks, not here.
Failing that, how do I adjust local_settings?

Chef Development Kit Version: 0.7.0
chef-client version: 12.4.1
berks version: 3.2.4
kitchen version: 1.4.2

host mac osx guest ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax is something like:

```
application "/var/www/myproj" do
  application_git do
    deploy_key repo_key
    repository repo_url
    revision repo_rev
  end
  virtualenv do
    path "/var/www/myproj/ve"
  end
  pip_requirements "/var/www/myproj/requirements/cpython2.txt"
  django do
    database "postgres://#{dbuser}:#{dbpassword}@#{dbserver}/#{dbname}"
    secret_key django_secret_key
    local_settings_source 'host_settings.py.erb'
    local_settings_options setting1: my_secret_1, setting2: my_secret_2
    local_settings_path "/var/www/myproj/settings/host_settings.py"
    migrate true
  end
end
```

A template named 'host_settings.py.erb' (in this case) should created, and look like this:

```
DEBUG = <%= PoisePython::Utils.to_python(@debug) %>

<%- unless @allowed_hosts.empty? -%>
ALLOWED_HOSTS = <%= PoisePython::Utils.to_python(@allowed_hosts) %>
<%- end -%>

# database connection information
DATABASES = <%= PoisePython::Utils.to_python(@databases) %>

# Django secret key
<%- if @secret_key -%>
SECRET_KEY = <%= PoisePython::Utils.to_python(@secret_key) %>
<%- end -%>

<%- if ! @setting1.to_s == '' -%>
# Setting #1
SECRET_1 = '<%= PoisePython::Utils.to_python(@setting1) %>'
<%- end -%>

<%- if ! @setting2.to_s == '' -%>
# Setting #2
SECRET_2 = '<%= PoisePython::Utils.to_python(@setting2) %>'
<%- end -%>
```

Source: https://github.com/poise/application_python/issues/59

Comment: txs for the info.  I am working on the application code right now, rather than Chef and I did workaround the whole thing by writing my whole settings.py from scratch rather than using the PoisePython stuff.  When I get back to Chef, probably in a few weeks, I'll see if I can quickly try out your suggestion.

Comment: It should work - I've used it on a couple of different deployments.